# Could a Snowball Earth drive us to extinction?

Tags: science-based, geography, climate

Could a [Snowball Earth](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth) drive our species into total extinction?

The most obvious problem is:

- How would we grow food to sustain any grouping of people?

Comment: I think you have 2 questions, would it drive us to extinction (because how would we grow food) and could we cause it to happen.

Comment: @bowlturner as I said the latter one is optional but bonus points to whoever answers both.

Comment: If you want to ask two questions they need to be two questions really, I've edited to remove the "bonus question". Feel free to ask it as a separate question though.

Comment: I think you could ask this question without the spoiler or plot summary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is fairly simple, it is a question of can habitats be built and food be grown that could survive in any way such an event? That is very clearly a yes. [Hydroponics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics) allows for food to be grown in a small area so humans would be able to create habitats in a variety of potential locations; including on [top of the ice possibly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_stations_in_Antarctica).

As for humans causing a snowball earth, that seems entirely possible; all that would be needed is some solution to global warming to be deployed and turn out to be much more effective than originally projected and continuing to be effective even as earth cools with an increased albedo due to snow and ice coverage.

Comment: Reminds me of [Fallen Angels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_Angels_%28science_fiction_novel%29). Global warming is the only thing keeping the next ice age at bay.

Answer (score 3):

Given spaceflight technology not too far advanced beyond present levels, avoiding a Snowball Earth scenario is fairly simple: place a sufficient number of mirrors in orbit to reflect enough additional sunlight on to the Earth to keep the temperature where you want it.  The materials can come from the moon, or asteroids.

Of course (even in the absence of human-caused global warming) a Snowball Earth isn't possible.  We have a pretty solid theory for the Ice Ages (basically the effects of the Milankovitch Cycles on the current configuration of the continents), per which the next Ice Age would be at least 10,000 years off: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles  And arguably, an Ice Age would be a net benefit, as we'd gain additional lands on the continental shelves, and have more precipitation in now-desert areas like the Sahara, Australia, and the western US.

Comment: Clearly you don't live in a northern latitude, like north of 45 degrees.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: I have lived much of my life at 45N or more, including some time above the Arctic Circle. Currently 39.5N, but ~5000 ft altitude, which is climactically better than 45N - and I wouldn't live here if the nearby mountains didn't make summers bearable.  I'd hate to live at this latitude at sea level, say in the Sacramento valley.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think that it is possible for humans to survive. I've done a lot of research for a school project on this exact topic.  I found that temperatures at the poles would be -50 degrees which is quite inhospitable.  But at the equator is -20, quite cold but it is bearable and many do live in those conditions.

As for food, I do believe that john is right about the hydroponics.

Comment: There isn't much information in this answer. If you have more information, you should write a fleshed out answer.

Comment: I would love to hear any information you have on the topic - maybe an except from your paper backed up by linking your sources?

Answer (score 0):

With sufficient funding we could (in theory) create self-sufficient colonies on Mars with currently available technology. It would have similar conditions as a Snowball Earth, with the added disadvantage of almost no atmosphere, much less water, and a very limited mass of materials we could ship there with rockets our technology is capable of building.

This means that our species could survive, but depending on how slow or fast it was happening, and how united we became in the effort, the size of the population being supported could vary wildly.

Comment: That is too great a supposition - we lack the knowledge of whether or not a human population would even be viable on Mars at all, much less whether or not we have the current technological capability. The drastically lower gravity, in addition to the difficulties of the environment, and technological difficulties make this dubious. Regardless, there is no circumstance, even total snowball, which makes Mars more plausible than habitats on Earth.